# Sendmail forwarding?

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I have `Sendmail` installed under Ubuntu 16.04.1. My needs are simple:

- Forward all email sent to *@domain.com to one specific gmail address

**EXCEPT**

- If email is sent to specificuser@domain.com, forward those messages to one specific gmail address (different gmail address than above). This user does not have an account on the server.

I know this is simple, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish it.

I've got a `virtusertable` that looks like this:

```
specificuser@domain.com     user2@gmail.com
@domain.com                 user1@gmail.com
```

Can anyone assist me in getting this configured, please? Thanks!

Comment: What happens at the moment? Does everything go to the default address or does nothing get forwarded? Do you get any errors? Have you tried using sendmail's rewrite test mode (`-bt`)?

Comment: Nothing gets forwarded at all -- not messages sent to specificuser@domain.com NOR anything sent to the domain.

Comment: What is reported/logged in sendmail's log files?

Answer (score 3):

**Install Prerequisites**

```
apt-get install sendmail mailutils sendmail-bin
```

**Create a Gmail Auth File**

Create the actual directory for the auth file

```
mkdir -m 700 /etc/mail/authinfo/
cd /etc/mail/authinfo/
```

Create the auth file itself

```
vi /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth
```

Put this in the contents of gmail-auth (make sure to put in the correct user/gmail/password(Also leave the prefixes U:user I:email P:password))

```
AuthInfo: "U:root" "I:YOUR GMAIL EMAIL ADDRESS" "P:YOUR PASSWORD"
```

Next you want to create the hash map for the authentication file

```
makemap hash gmail-auth < gmail-auth
```

**Configure Your Sendmail**

Add the following block of code *right above first "MAILER" definition line*

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp.gmail.com]')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 587')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/authinfo/gmail-auth.db')dnl
```

Next you have to compile the sendmail configuration.

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Restart sendmail to pick up the changes

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail reload
```

**Configuration Test**

```
echo "Just testing my sendmail gmail relay" | mail -s "Sendmail gmail Relay" my-email@my-domain.com
```

At this point you should have the relay working.  Now we will move on to the virtusertable.

**Virtusertable**

In order to create virtusertable mappings, you must first create a text file in the /etc/mail/ directory of your server. Each entry in a virtusertable should be on a single line. The original recipient address on the left hand side, with one or more spaces or tabs separating it from the right hand side, which contains the destination address.

Example:

```
vi /etc/mail/virtusertable

user@domain.com    user@gmail.com
@domain.com        master@domain.com
```

Any time you make a change to the /etc/mail/virtusertable text file, you will need to create a db file that sendmail can read. The following command will create the /etc/mail/virtusertable.db file when run by root:

```
makemap hash /etc/mail/virtusertable < /etc/mail/virtusertable
```

Now restart sendmail and all should be functioning as expected.

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail reload
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't see where those steps take into account my need to forward email to a specific user's gmail box. Where do I configure that?

Comment: Figured we could address that after you get the forward working.

Comment: OK. I followed the steps you provided (thanks again!) and the "echo "Just testing my sendmail gmail relay" | mail -s "Sendmail gmail Relay" my-email@my-domain.com" worked as expected. I also sent from another email to my server's email address, and it worked as expected. So far, so good! I tried sending to <random>@server, and that worked too! Next question... How do I configure it to send specific user's email to her gmail?

Comment: Specifically how is the smtp server receiving the mail?  I get that you want it routed to user@gmail.com, but how is it being generated and how is it being handled now? (sorry if I'm overlooking already supplied information)

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question. I am a Google Apps user, and my domain used to work as I desired. My wife recently changed her Gmail address and I cannot find where to change the forwarding from <specificnanw>@mydomain.com to her new Gmail address. It's been so long since I configured it that I frankly forgot. And I don't know where to start looking...

Comment: Added the last step of virtusertable.  Hope this resolves your issue

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am receiving these errors (two messages, below) now:

Comment: /etc/init.d/sendmail reload
 * Reloading Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail                                                                                                                    554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 2028: unknown configuration line "define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp.gmail.com]')dnl"
554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 2029: unknown configuration line "define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP h 587')dnl"
554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 2030: unknown configuration line "define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP h 587')dnl"

Comment: 554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 2031: unknown configuration line "define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A p')dnl"
554 5.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 2033: unknown configuration line "define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl"
451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 2034: fileclass: cannot open 'ATURE(`authinfo',`hash': No such file or directory

Comment: What did you change?  Nothing in modifying the vertusertable would have caused this.  You could paste the sendmail.cf (remove sensitive data) to pastebin along with the error log.  Otherwise start over and repeat the steps provided.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ssmtp?

SMTP is a program which delivers email from a local computer to a configured mailhost (mailhub)

with gmail setup

http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-ssmtp.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP

Comment: Will sSMTP do what I require? If so, do I need to remove Sendmail?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to authenticate with Gmail to sent the messages.  Otherwise the mail may be treated as Spam.   This is done by configuring a client password (where your server is the client) entry.

For an Exim4 install I would do the following:

- Configure the server to use one of Gmail's MX addresses as a smarthost (with authentication);
- Configure a wildcard alias for the your domain; and
- Setup a wildcard alias alias for the domain.

The default alias router doesn't handle wildcards, but it is a simple modification to add wildcards.

These steps apply for pretty well any server software you want to use.  Some software may default to using a smarthost.

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail consults virtusertable only for deliveries to email addresses in local email domains (`$=w`) and domains listed in `$={VirtHost}`.
Sendmail by default adds some names to `$=w` automatically.

You can check the above lists (classes) using as root the commands below

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
echo '$={VirtHost}' | sendmail -bt
```

1. You can add domain.com to `$={VirtHost}` in `sendmail.mc`

   LOCAL_CONFIG
   C{VirtHost} domain.com
   divert(0)dnl
2. You can allow relaying **to** the domain from anywhere on the internet with the following access-table entry:

   `to:domain.com  RELAY`

**WARNINGS**
A) Because it will leave envelope sender unchanged gmail may reject or treat as spam some forwarded messages
B) Such forwarding to gmail is not recommended without anti-spam filtering
=> I would recommend (slightly) more complicated solution with relaying via procmail script.  It will rewrite envelope sender and provide anti-spam hook